# Java - Converting a string into a rectangle

Tags: java, string, type-conversion, rectangles

I am reading a string from a file and I am getting a string variable from it. I would like to convert it into a rectangle variable. I am using the scanner class to read from the file. Here is my code.

```
    r = new Rectangle[ed];
        for(int i = 0;i < ed; i++){
            String rs = roomInfo.nextLine();
            r[i] = new Rectangle(rs);
    }
```

In my code I am reading from the file into a string and then you can see how I tried to convert it to a rectangle.

Comment: What do you mean Rectangle? There is no native variable called Rectangle.. Do you mean adding the String as an attribute to an object called Rectangle?

Comment: I am importing "import java.awt.Rectangle;"

Comment: Ok, you should look at the documentation, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html. There is only one method that supports Strings for the Rectangle library and thats the toString() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should in some way parse the `String` into numbers, then you can create `Rectangle` objects from it.

Say, your string looks like this:

```
"0, 0, 20, 20"
```

That's

```
"<x>, <y>, <width>, <hight>"
```

Then here's what you have to do:

```
String[] split = str.split("[,]");
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(split[0], split[1], split[2], split[3]);
```

---

Other string formats require other techniques.

Comment: Thank you very much this was a huge help and it got my project back on its feet.

Comment: @Oak One thing I forgot, `String`s are not `int`s you still require to convert it by `Integer.parseInt(myString);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to string rect with flattenToString

```
String str = rect.flattenToString();
```

and string format will be like this

```
str = "0 -593 933 1066"
```

with this format, recovering string to rect is

```
Rect rect = Rect.unflattenFromString(str);
```